# Matlab display a variable from function

Tags: matlab

I'm new to Matlab and I have a function and I need to display a variable from running the main file (but the main file does access the function)...

I have tried to use fprintf(n);

Thanks :)

Comment: This is not very clear - can you give more details?

Comment: @mathematician1975 His question is clear, I am worried about how you interpret questions :/
He needs to display a variable(which has been set) in the console.

Comment: @KarlMorrison I find it unclear but of course you are entitled to your opinion. What do you hope to achieve though by commenting on a comment to a question that has an answer that was accepted over 2 years ago?

Comment: @mathematician1975 Trying to help you become a better person of course! Try and see things from a beginners perspective and not an  elitists perspective, not ruling you out as an elitist but a lot of people (especially from the mathematics community) always need perfectly formulated questions, a dangerous requirement which leads to discouragement. And individuals ask why people hate math for example!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MATLAB function `fprintf()` is very similar to `fprintf()` in C. If your variable `n` is an integer, then you should do

```
fprintf('%d\n', n);
```

An interesting feature is that you can also print multiple numeric values and literal text to the screen. For example

```
A1 = [9.9, 9900];
A2 = [8.8,  7.7 ; ...
      8800, 7700];
fprintf('X is %4.2f meters or %8.3f mm\n', A1, A2);
```

where `%4.2f` takes the element at the first column of `A1` and `%8.3f` takes the second. In the sequence, it repeats for `A2` printing its first line and later its second line. The output is

```
X is 9.90 meters or 9900.000 mm
X is 8.80 meters or 8800.000 mm
X is 7.70 meters or 7700.000 mm
```

If you want more details about the specifiers you can use with `fprintf()`, you should give a look at the [MathWorks docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html).

Comment: You could also use disp()